# Show that the ideal is finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with unity $1_{R}$. Let $X=\{ f_i|i \in I \}$ where I is some index set and $f_i \in R$. I want to show that if the ideal generated by $X$ is all of $R$, then $X$ is actually finitely generated.

My attempt: If I could show that $1_R$ is represented by finitely many elements of $X$, then we're done. If $I$ is finite, then this is trivial. Otherwise, in the infinite case, when we consider an element $r$ is in a so-called "span" of a set, then it is a finite linear combination of these elements- hence set $r = 1_R$. However, this seems a little gimmicky and not a rigorous proof.

Comment: Do you mean to say "if the ideal generated by $X$ is all of $R$, then $X$ is finite", as opposed to finitely generated? $X$ is just a set, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Not every commutative ring with unity is finitely generated; take $R=k[t]$ with your favourite field $k$. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: I might be interpreting the question incorrectly, it's #2 in the link http://www.math.tamu.edu/graduate/phd/quals/nalgebra/j12.pdf

Comment: Your idea is the right one. If the ideal $I$ generated by $X$ is $R$, then by definition, $1_{R}$ belongs to $I$, and so must be a *finite* $R$-linear combination of elements of $X$. (Remember what the definition of the ideal generated by $X$ is - it is the set of all $R$-linear combinations of elements of $X$, where all but finitely many of the coefficients are $0$!) These finitely many elements generating $1$ will be your generators of $I$.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking Alex! Thank you

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful! (I should note that your "infinite" case does not make any sense to me, at least as written - but this is not a problem, since there is no reason to break into cases in the first place.)

Comment: Sure, I was just making the distinction as to where my confusion was.